# Video on multiple monitors

Tags: video, fullscreen, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I am writing a, relatively, simple program involving 3 separate monitors.

Each monitor will have a button moving around that specific screen. If you click that button it will play a video on that screen. I need to be able to have each of the screens acting as if they are totally separate.

I have built the computer that will be running this. 2 graphics cards (4 dvi slots). 3 touch screen monitors. Decent computer set up.

My question is this: What is the best approuch for this? I have never programmed in video into anything I have written. I just need a jump start on where to go.

I cant afford any real software. Open source everything would be great.
I am running Windows XP home (updated all the way)
This machine will only be doing this (its an exhibit)

Any help would be great. What language do you suggest? Thanks all!

Comment: I seem to recall the original WPF demos had a button moving around the screen...!

Comment: Sheese, you can aford all that kit, but nothing left for the software?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your programming experience has been, so I'm not sure whether this is helpful or not, but have you had a look at [Processing](http://processing.org/)? It's an open source programming environment based on Java for (from the website) "students, artists, designers, researchers, and hobbyists for learning, prototyping, and production".

I think it should be capable of doing everything you need for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently got my degree in Computer Science. So I am still fresh to everything.

TFD: The kit was all paid for  by the museum. I guess I could ask for more money, but I am under some time limits (like they want something by this weekend). Kinda sucks.

I will check out Processing and see if I can use it.

I guess I am looking for a nudge in the right direction. I will probably end up slapping something together as a temporary solution. Then when I have a chance go back and fix it up.

Comment: It's normally considered best to include this sort of thing as an edit to the original question.

Comment: Ya I figured I was doing it wrong :-/. New to the site.

Plus I was having issues with my OpenID so I had to make a newish post. Next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio (Express) to create application in .net, create an form with some buttons and media player control, then loop each screen and place one instance of this form on exact screen bounds and that is.

Use this code snipet as reference:

```
public static void PutOn(this Form form, int width, int height)
{
    var screen_size = new Size(width, height);

    var screens = from s in Screen.AllScreens
                  where s.Bounds.Size == screen_size
                  select s;

    Screen app_screen = screens.FirstOr(Screen.PrimaryScreen);

    form.Location = new Point(
        app_screen.Bounds.X + (app_screen.Bounds.Width - form.Width) / 2,
        app_screen.Bounds.Y + (app_screen.Bounds.Height - form.Height) / 2);
}
```